# Tracking file structure

Tags: git, file-management

git is good for tracking plain text and source code, but not for big or binary files.

What is an efficient way of tracking file structure? By that I mean just their names not content. (This is helpful for large library of eBooks or media)

What I tried: a `git` pre-commit hook to save output of `tree` in some text file. I was wondering if `git` has a functionality of tracking only the first n lines of some file types. If so, then all binary file types can be tracked by git using their names only.

Comment: Git is symmetrical by design: what you commit is what you get on checkout. There are ways to break this symmetry, but it's asking for trouble. If you insist, look into `clean` filters.

Answer (score 2):

Git doesn't have any built-in features for this, but it's possible to do achieve it using custom Git hooks, e.g. "clean/smudge" filters, or using wrapper tools around `git add`.

The [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) project does this, mostly using Git hooks so that the repository only keeps track of symlinks instead of actual files. It's pretty much designed for personal media archival, with its own subcommands to transfer data between repositories.

The [Git-LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) project works in a similar way, but is oriented more towards centralized "code + assets" repositories where all clients check out binary data from the same central storage server.